# VB6 New form/msgbox pops up behind parent form On Win7

Tags: windows, windows-7, vb6

I have a window form application written in vb6.  It works fine  until our users upgraded their workstation recently from WinXP to Win7.  Hers is the detail of the issue:

A child form or message box opens behind a parent form.  Users cannot do anything because the application is focused on the child form/messagebox. They have to kill the whole application using the task management. Also, this issue happens randomly (one or twice a day).  I cannot replicate the issue in my development workstation.  Does anyone have the similar issue?  or any suggestion would be helpful?

I tried the following things on users' machines, but none of them works:

1. Set the application to run in compatibility mode for Windows XP (Service Pack 3).
2. Grant users local admin right on their workstations.
3. Make sure all references and components on users' machine are same version as our development workstation.

Thank you very much

Below is the code to popup a child window:

```
frmClinicalQuestion2.txtCQTwoComments.Text = Trim(m_QViolComm)
frmClinicalQuestion2.txtCQTwoHistoryComments.Text = Trim(m_QViolHistComm)
Call SetValues(txtQ2, OptQ2, m_QViol)
Call SetValues(frmClinicalQuestion2.txtCQTwo, frmClinicalQuestion2.OptCQTwo, m_QViolHist)
frmClinicalQuestion2.Show 1, frmClinical
```

Here is how to unload the form:

```
Unload frmClinicalQuestion2
```

Comment: Would need some code examples in order to replicate and look for solution

Comment: Is the parent form (frmClinical) set as "topmost" when showing the child form, e.g. using `SetWindowPos(frmClinical.hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE)`? If it's the case, then children forms must also be made topmost, usually in their `Form_Activate()` event handler.
But the randomness would then only be explainable if: (1) making frmClinical topmost is optional (set by the user, e.g. in options); or (2) if the topmost flag is actually not set by your program but through another program (an AHK script, a window / virtual desktop manager like Dexpot, AquaSnap, etc.)

Comment: Is frmClinicalQuestion2 the definition of the form or a declared instance? Although allowed, you can run into serious issues using the "default" reference. Do `Dim lfrmClinicalQuestion2 as New frmClinicalQuestion2`. Use this reference when setting various values of the form, then do `lfrmClinicalQuestion2.Show vbModal` The same would go for `frmClinical` and any other forms you call from your application. I've never run into an instance of forms not showing up in the proper z order when using instances as described.

Comment: @johnwait I don't see any code that sets the parent form as "topmost" in my program.  I will look into second suggestion.

Comment: To test this theory, next time it happens (and you have access to the window/desktop of the user), try to check if the disabled (parent) window has the [WS_EX_TOPMOST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx#WS_EX_TOPMOST) extended window style. You can't really use Spy++ (I'm pretty much sure its EULA would forbid use on additional computers), but there's a VS2005 C++ project [here (codeproject.com)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9549/Capturing-Window-Controls-and-Modifying-their-prop) that you can compile to look at the styles of a window.

Comment: Revisiting your code, you wrote `frmClinicalQuestion2.Show 1, frmClinical` which is really `frmClinicalQuestion2.Show vbModal, frmClinical`. But OwnerForm (the 2nd parameter of `frmClinicalQuestion2.Show`) is normally _only_ used with vbModeless. I don't know what the behaviour is when specifying an owner window with vbModal, but if you use vbModal (i.e. only this window should remain on top until closed) I say it would be safe not to specify anything for the OwnerForm parameter.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the application to run in compatibility mode for Windows XP (Service Pack 3), The frequency of the issue has been reduced from 2~3 daily to 1~2 weekly.  Users are OK with this solution now.  We are going to rewrite the project using .NET framework soon. Thank you @johnwait and @Craig Johnson for giving me suggestions.